# RazorPDF resources

Tags: pdf, razor, model-view-controller, converters

Hello guys i've install a RazorPDF to my project via nuget. and when i try to render my page i got this error:

```
Helvetica not found as resource.
 RazorPDF.Legacy.Text.Pdf.Type1Font..ctor(String afmFile, String enc, Boolean emb, Byte[] ttfAfm, Byte[] pfb, Boolean forceRead) +894
   RazorPDF.Legacy.Text.Pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont(String name, String encoding, Boolean embedded, Boolean cached, Byte[] ttfAfm, Byte[] pfb, Boolean noThrow, Boolean forceRead) +1056
   RazorPDF.Legacy.Text.Pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont(String name, String encoding, Boolean embedded, Boolean cached, Byte[] ttfAfm, Byte[] pfb, Boolean noThrow) +81
   RazorPDF.Legacy.Text.Pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont(String name, String encoding, Boolean embedded) +74
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a defective iTextsharp assembly. You get that error when the font metric tables are not embedded in the assembly.

Comment: and how i can fix it?

Comment: You can get the oficial assembly [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/).

Comment: its installed via nugget, i didn't think that it makes an error

Comment: Are you running it in full trust mode? It won't work in partial trust unless a lot of changes are made in itextsharp code.

Comment: Paulo, how would I set it to full trust mode please? I have VS2015